# Joomla , mi pagina se descarga

Tags: php, joomla3

Mi pagina se descarga cuando ingresas al dominio y no se a que se debe este error.

cuando agrego esto al htacces no se descarga la pagina pero sale error 500

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

para prueba de la pagina http://ecoversa.org/

Answer (score 1):

Es realmente extraño, nunca me ha sucedido algo así.

Podrías probar renombrando el archivo .htaccess y comprobando nuevamente lo que sucede  o bien ingresando a la IP http://143.95.228.87/~nameX donde nameX es tu nombre de usuario para ingresar al panel de control o las primeras letras del mismo (son sólo los primeros 5 caracteres).

Comment: vale morgan haré lo de la configuración y te comento que paso gracias